# Cancelling / stopping an executing method (selector) - Objective-C, iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hifellows, please consider following scenario:

I have 3 methods, where on each create and add some objects like imageviews,activityindicators,etc.

So imagine:

```
    - (void)anim1 {
    // do some verifications like internet reachability. So create imageview1, imageview2, imageview3, activityindicator then add to subView.

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0.3 options:0 animations:^{

            // Animate the alpha value of your imageView from 1.0 to 0.0 here
            //...

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            if(![(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] hasConnectivity])
            {
      NSLog(@"No Internet...");
    return;
            }
            else { 
    // If i got internet connection, i create another imageview (checked image) and add to subview. So play with alpha animations then call the second method.

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 delay:0.8 options:0 animations:^{
                    someobject.alpha = 0.0f;
                    [someobject setAlpha:0.5f];
                    [someobject setAlpha:0.5f];

                } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    [self performSelector:@selector(anim2) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
                    NSLog(@"Got Internet...");
                }];

                return;
            }
        }];
    }
```

So... anim2:

```
    - (void)anim2 {
    // do some URL connections (POST FORM) with blocks using AFNetworking framework. So, depending on results of URL connection, i work with imageview2, add an activityindicator (while URL processing) then add to subView. To resume, let consider this:

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.somepage.com"]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) { 
    NSLog(@"Response OK..");

    // Here i create another imageview (checked image) and add to subview. So play with alpha animations then call the third method.

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 delay:0.8 options:0 animations:^{
                                            someobject.alpha = 0.0f;
                                            [someobject setAlpha:0.5f];
                                            [someobject setAlpha:0.5f];

                                        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                        [self performSelector:@selector(anim3) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
                                        }];

    }

    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Response error. Aborting.");
     }

    }];
        [operation start];

    }
```

Finally, anim3 method:

```
    - (void)anim3 {
    // Work with imageview3, another activityindicator, then after animation delay, i create a new imageview (checked image). Then enable a uibutton.
    ...

    }
```

So, when i start anim1, it do the verifications, then follow 'sequence', calling anim2... And so on... Anim1 = OK -> Anim2 = OK -> Anim3 -> Button enabled -> Clicked -> Set all imageviews to alpha = 0.70f.

All works as well, but i have create an another method to 'clean' these views, then start again.

Basically, it cancels all selectors, then removesfromSuperView all imageviews that have been created. And, call anim1 again.

Please consider:

```
    -(void)cleanAnimViews
    {

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(anim1)         object:nil];
        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(anim2) object:nil];
        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(anim3) object:nil];

    NSArray* subviews = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: scrollview.subviews];
        for (UIView* view in subviews) {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIActivityIndicatorView class]]) {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
        for (UIView* view in subviews) {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag == 200) {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag == 201) {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag == 202) {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag == 203) {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIActivityIndicatorView class]] && view.tag == 204) {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag == 250) {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
        [self performSelector:@selector(anim1) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.8];

    }
```

I call to '**cleanAnimViews**' on **viewWillAppear**, and using a **RefreshControl object**.
**My problem:**
When all tasks (think anim1, anim2 and anim3) *already done*, THEN i call 'cleanAnimViews' using pull to refresh, **it beautifully removes all imageviews then start again from first method (anim1).**

But, if i call 'cleanAnimViews' using pull to refresh **during animX proccessing** (between anim1 to anim2, or anim2 to anim3), i got mess because the 'cleanAnimViews' removes all imageviews, but the 'anim1 -> anim2 -> anim3' continues being processing at same time... So, i got two (or three) activityindicator (eg: from anim1 and anim3), mess with objects controls, because it executing an older 'proccess' on anim2 (eg) and new one to anim1 in sametime...

**Let me explain better:**

viewDidAppear ->

**started anim1:**
... This created the 3 images... Create ActivityIndicator... Verification has done... Create a "checked" imageview... So it *perform selector anim2*.

**started anim2...**
... This works with objects controls, Create ActivityIndicator, Verification has done... Create a "checked" imageview...

----> **NOW i call "cleanAnimViews"** from pull to refresh. ***But the anim2 already performed selector anim3...***

So, it removes all imageview and at end of method start anim1 again (from cleanAnimViews), and as anim3 method already has started, it create imageviews, activityindicator and checked image again.. AND anim1 is doing ALL the process again on same time..

There is a way to 'cancel/stop' these animX method when i call 'cleanAnimViews'?
I ask this because when the view disappear and appear again all works beautifully. It stops all animX, and when appear again call anim1 again...

I have tried creating a BOOL flag on 'cleanAnimViews', then play with it on animX methods.. but dont works..

Sorry for long post, typos, and if i didn't so much clear... But i got no more idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to cancel all animation on your `someObject` so you have to call `[someObject.layer removeAllAnimations];`.

PS Don't forget to add `QuartzCore` so that you can access the `layer`.

Comment: On each method (anim1, anim2, anim3) i have an instantiated uiimageview object, lets call to someObject1, someObject2 and someObject3.
    So on anim1:
    [mySuperView addSubview:someObject1];

In anim2:
    [mySuperView addSubview:someObject2];

In anim3:
    [mySuperView addSubview:someObject3];

Then, in "cleanAnimViews" method, i used:
    [someObject1.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [someObject2.layer removeAllAnimations];
    [someObject3.layer removeAllAnimations];
But it dont works... (I already have QC framework)